Android TV app rejected with reason "No full-size app banner and/or icon"
I know this is not a programming related question but we are getting a bit frustrated trying to update a pre existing TV app on Google Play.
Google reviewed the app and rejected it, although it was just an update to an already approved TV App, with no changes to Images/banners etc. This is the first time it happened. The reason given by google was
"Issue found: No full-size app banner and/or icon
Your app should contain a full-size app banner and icon that is visible in the launcher. We are targeting 1080P, which we consider xhdpi. Apps should include the banner in the xhdpi (320 dpi) drawables folder with a size of (320px × 180px) and the icon with a size of (512px x512px). Please refer to our Home screen banner.
The title should help users identify apps in the launcher. Please refer to our Visual design and user interaction documentation for more information.
Your icon does not fill the entire icon space."
We checked that the icons and banners had no transparency, that the banner had the app name on it etc...
We re-created all icons and TV banners using Android Studio's Image asset Wizards, to make sure we comply with the guidelines. We submitted the app again but got rejected with the same reason.
Has anybody had the same issue lately (April 2024)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

We had received the same reason for rejection. The app submitted does have a 320 * 180 banner defined in the manifest contain the name of the app on it. Also, the high-res icon 512 * 512. The rejection reasons are particularly unclear about this.
We're following the guidelines for tv apps as suggested - https://developer.android.com/design/ui/tv/guides/system/tv-app-icon-guidelines
If you have noticed the app icons that Image Asset Studio generates are different from what we have in the updated guidelines(https://developer.android.com/design/ui/tv/guides/system/tv-app-icon-guidelines#launcher-icon), It denoted that the app should contain at least a 160x160 pixel (at xhdpi density), but this isn't specifically mentioned in the rejection reason. So, if you haven't tried already update the icons to the latest recommended tv app icon dimensions, and see if it makes any difference.
Use the official figma template for generating the banner & icons - https://www.figma.com/community/file/1283953738855070149/tv-app-icon-template-android-tv-google-tv
If the issue still persists, submit an an appeal for better clarity.

We got the same rejection and even if the guidelines say minimum 160x160, Google's message says 512x512 (which we actually think is the store listing app icon size).
However, the problem is that the icon gets cut off by Google's circle filter.
To solve that, we made the icon size bigger without increasing the size of the image in it. And by temporarily drawing a full circle on top of the icon, we could see where the limits were. And then the icon was approved by Google. Make sure that the background is not transparent because then it will not be approved.
But that made the icon look very small on phones. So the the original icon can be kept in the drawable-xhdpi folder and  the 512x512 sized rounding safe icon can be placed in the drawable-television-xhdpi folder, so there will be a specific icon for televisions and the original icon for all other form factors.

Make different sizes of mipmap for banners
hdpi - 240x135
mdpi - 160x90
xhdpi - 320x180
xxhdpi - 480x270
xxxhdpi - 640x360
also, create icon but for xhdpi the icon size should have to be 512x512
don't forget to write name of your app in the banner.

The problem is not in the APK or in your app. The problem is in the icon uploaded in Google Play Console, in the Store Listings part.
Go to "Grow Users" / "Store Presence" / "Store Listings" / "Default Store Listing" / "Graphics" / "App Icon" and make sure the app icon is 512x512 pixels, and doesn't have transparent background - instead fill the icon background by a solid color. The icon doesn't have to be circular or any fancy shape - plain old rectangular will do. Then, resubmit your app.
